# Animate navigation bar from translucent to transparent

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I want to change the navigation bar from translucent to transparent with animation during a push segue but it becomes transparent immediately.

I extended the navigation controller:

```
    func setNavigationBarTransparent(transparent:Bool, animated:Bool) {

    // If current state of navigation bar is desired state then abort
    if barIsTransparent == transparent { return }

    // Reset transparency status
    barIsTransparent = transparent

    // Define transparency
    let image: UIImage? = transparent ? UIImage() : nil

    // Define animation
    let duration: NSTimeInterval = animated ? 0.3 : 0.0

    // Style navigation bar
    UIView.animateWithDuration(
        duration,
        animations: {
            self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
            self.navigationBar.shadowImage = image
    })
}
```

I call `setNavigationBarTransparent(true, animated: true)` in the destination view controller's `viewWillAppear`. The transition of the bar transparency is smooth during the segue as long as the navigation bar has no background image, i.e. it has no other view behind it because it is translucent. When I scroll up the collection view so that there is an image behind the translucent navigation bar, the transparency happens suddenly with zero duration.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update:** Just saw that during the reverse segue the bar does not actually change it's image from transparent to translucent but the frame slides in from above. So it would be sufficient for the bar's frame to slide out to above during the "translucent to transparent" segue.

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: @BorisNikolić I could not solve it. It would probably be solvable with a custom transition but that was too much work. So I simply used the standard transition animation for the navigation bar.

Comment: @BorisNikolić did you solve it?

Comment: @SAHM nope, I changed the design :)